# DevOps Build with localization resources

Tags: msbuild, localization, nuget, azure-devops

I'm trying to build a solution using Azure DevOps and publish the result as a nuGet package in a private repository.

A project in the solution contains a localized resource `Language.resx` containing the English texts.
The localized versions are:
`Language.da.resx`, `Language.se.resx` and `Language.no.resx` yet none of these are included in the resulting nuget package.

I tried adding `/target:Resource,Compile` to the MSBuild arguments property of the Build Solution task in DevOps, but it just resulted in an error saying no 'Resource' target was found.

I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious, but I just can't see it.
I must be close, the nuGet package gets published after all, and works, except for the localization resources.

I inspected the resulting nuGet Package and extracted the DLL from the project in question. Opening the DLL in .Net Reflector 10 shows me that it does indeed contain the text strings in English, but no other languages.

Comment: What type of project is this? an SDK-based multi-targeting or .net standard / core project vs a classic csproj (long, lists individual files)? are you using a nuspec file to pack?

Comment: .Net standard class library in multi-project solution, but the used build profile only builds one class library project in the solution. not using a nuspec file, I have no experience with those (yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the localized ressources were indeed built by default, though not visible in `.Net Reflector 10`.
The reason is that they weren't included in the nuGet package in the Packaging task.

A bit of research lead me to add a `.nuspec` file to the project.
In this file, I specified the relevant files etc. and they are now included in the nuGet package.

Not ideal though, since the list of files and dependencies now have to be maintained manually. But I was unable to find a way of making it dynamic.
Most of the details in the .nuspec file was possible to be made dynamic though, using variables referring to the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.

I ended up with the following content in the `.nuspec` file (some details cleaned though, since this is displayed in public)
Note: The word `Release` in the `src` attribute of the `files` section is the name of my build profile. Your solution might use a different name.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <!-- The identifier that must be unique within the hosting gallery -->
        <id>$id$</id>

        <!-- The package version number that is used when resolving dependencies -->
        <version>$version$</version>

        <!-- Authors contain text that appears directly on the gallery -->
        <authors>$author$</authors>

        <!-- 
            Owners are typically nuget.org identities that allow gallery
            users to easily find other packages by the same owners.  
        -->
        <owners>$author$</owners>

        <!-- License and project URLs provide links for the gallery -->
        <!--<licenseUrl></licenseUrl>-->
        <!--<projectUrl></projectUrl>-->

        <!-- The icon is used in Visual Studio's package manager UI -->
        <!--<iconUrl></iconUrl>-->

        <!-- 
            If true, this value prompts the user to accept the license when
            installing the package. 
        -->
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>

        <!-- Any details about this particular release -->
        <!--<releaseNotes></releaseNotes>-->

        <!-- 
            The description can be used in package manager UI. Note that the
            nuget.org gallery uses information you add in the portal. 
            Must be included, and must never be empty.
        -->
        <description>$description$</description>

        <!-- Copyright information -->
        <copyright>$copyright$</copyright>

        <!-- Tags appear in the gallery and can be used for tag searches -->
        <!--<tags></tags>-->

        <!-- Dependencies are automatically installed when the package is installed -->
        <dependencies>
            <dependency id="MicrosoftOfficeCore" version="15.0.0" />
            <dependency id="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word" version="15.0.4797.1003" />
        </dependencies>
    </metadata>

    <!-- Files to include in the package -->
    <files>
        <file src="bin\Release\$id$.dll" target="lib\net462\$id$.dll" />
        <file src="bin\Release\da\$id$.resources.dll" target="lib\net462\da\$id$.resources.dll" />
        <file src="bin\Release\no\$id$.resources.dll" target="lib\net462\no\$id$.resources.dll" />
        <file src="bin\Release\sv\$id$.resources.dll" target="lib\net462\sv\$id$.resources.dll" />
    </files>
</package>
```